# Asynchronous function in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I use express 4+ and i have a registration route that made and asynchroneous call before render the page. the code is below:

```
router.get('/registration' , (req , res)=>{
  let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
  query.equalTo('public',true);

  query.find().then((rs)=>{
    let roles = rs.map((r)=>{
      return {'id':r.id , 'name':r.get('ui_name')}
    });
    res.render('registration/registration.njk' , {roles:roles});
  } , (error , code)=>{
    res.send(new Error(500));
  })

})
```

The problems is when i do that, all the middlewares are called twice and all sessions data and cookie  is removed. This cause problems because i can't fetch current user.

How can i prevent this ?

Comment: You will have to show more context.  This is one route handler that has nothing to do with middleware so there's no way we can assess your issue with middleware.

Comment: I found the solution, i made a request inside a route middleware to the api inside the projet. This trigger the middleware twice. But without sesion data.

Comment: You should not need to call your own API at that level. You can just create a function that get the results and use that in the route and then you can call the function internally without running into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use persistent session to complete your work flow, looks like due to non-persistent session your previous session data getting over-written. Please refer to the options your session middleware provides one of the option would be helpful to make it store the session you're already using.

If possible please mention which session middleware you're using.